# Swapping Two Objects In An ArrayList

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, wrapper, file-handling

I am trying to swap 2 objects within an `ArrayList`. To accomplish this, I am creating a new list where the objects are swapped, then overwrite the *old* list entirely with the, *swapped* list. However, I am having trouble adding the objects from the old list to the new list.

The program takes input from a text file, reads the data into objects (circles and rectangles, which are extensions of `GeometricObject`) and then adds those objects to an `ArrayList` called `objectList`.

Here is the code:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void swapCells
(ArrayList<E> objectList, int left, int right) {

    /* The user may enter the two indices, "left,"
     * and, "right," in any order which they desire.
     * Because of this it will be necessary to determine
     * which is larger or "right" index, and which is
     * the smaller or "left" index
     */

    int temp;
    ArrayList<GeometricObject> swappedList = new ArrayList<GeometricObject>();

    if (left > right) {

        // Exchanges left and right
        temp = left;
        left = right;
        right = temp;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {

        if (i == left) {
            swappedList.add(objectList.get(right));
            System.out.println( swappedList.get(i).getArea());
        } else {
            swappedList.add((E) objectList.get(i));

        }

    }

} // End of swapCells
```

I get the following syntax error, and do not know what to do about it.

> The method `add(GeometricObject)` in the type `ArrayList<GeometricObject>` is not applicable for the arguments `(E)`

The error is specifically at, `swappedList.add(objectList.get(right));` and also `wappedList.add((E) objectList.get(i));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe this is exactly the answer your looking for, but it may help.

If you typecast with GeomtricObject you will get a functioning code, however, this defeats the purpose of using a generic if your just going to force it into a Geometric Object.

You also need to add else if to get the left object swapped to right position

You may also want to print out the swappedList to confirm that the action has been completed.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) 
            {
                if (i == left) {
                    swappedList.add((GeometricObject) objectList.get(right));
                }else if (i == right)
                    swappedList.add((GeometricObject) objectList.get(left));
                else {
                    swappedList.add((GeometricObject) objectList.get(i));
            }
        }
```

EDIT 2:
The following will aid you in the operation you were looking for in generics.

You will need to make a temp and cast it to E. You will also need to use the following code as well in its correct arguments and/or form / notation.

```
        E temp
        List.set(____ , _____)
        List.get(____ )
```

If your still having trouble with this swap function look at one that is not Generic.

EDIT 3:
You most likely have the same problem as I do, and you also need to sort the Generic. You can use the selectionSort Method below to help you on the assignment. You will need to change the method so that it works for an ArrayList instead of a Array. This means you will need to make use of the suggestions in EDIT 2 to modify the code below. You may also need to use the compareTo Method.

```
        private static void selectionSort(int[] list, int low, int high) { 
        if (low < high) { 
          int posMax = high; 
          int theMax = list[high]; 
          for (int i = 0; i < high; i++) { 
            if (list[i] > theMax) { 
              theMax = list[i]; 
              posMax = i; 
            }// if 
          }// for 
        list[posMax] = list[high]; 
        list[high] = theMax; 
        selectionSort(list, low, high - 1); 
        }// if 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add `E` objects to a list of `GeometricObject`. That’s why you get an error. Your list `swappedList` should be of type `ArrayList<E>`, or better: `List<E>`.

On the other hand, you can modify the type of the function to:

```
public static void swapCells(ArrayList<GeometricObject> objectList, int left, int right)
```

Oh, and do something with this list you’ve built. Your current code just discards it.

Comment: What do you mean by that last part?

Comment: The object `swappedList` isn’t returned by your swapCells function, nor put into some other variable. Hence, it disappears at the end of your function body.

Comment: When I make the swapped list into type <E> it makes me cast to use my GeometricObject functions. I do not like this way so much anymore, is there another way? I suppose add, and remove to the original objectList would work, but is there anything else?

Comment: Right thats because I was hung up, I was going to make objectList equal to swappedList, simply replacing objectList altogether. Something just seems amiss with this whole thing, like im making it harder than it should be...

Comment: Instead of using a generic type <E>, you can change the type of swapCells to: `public static void swapCells(ArrayList<GeometricObject> objectList, int left, int right)`

Comment: You planned to do: `objectList = swappedList;` at the end of your function? that wouldn’t have worked because you would be assigning to a local variable. But if you planned to modify objectList, just modify it, no need to copy it.

Comment: No I can't do it that way, our teacher wants us to understand the way that generics works. That's the one thing I'm pretty sure I have to keep the same. I would have went to my teacher and asked about it, but he doesn't really check his email and it's Saturday so there are no tutors up at the school so I'm kind of at a loss there. I do need to modify object list, that's the whole point of this, so should I just do, "add" and, "remove" on objectList or something?

Comment: I also forgot to mention, I do appreciate your quick response to my question.

Comment: If you need to use generics, then switching the type of swappedList to `ArrayList<E>` *is* the solution. Then return it from you swappedCells methods. Outside of the swappedCells method, it will have another type (the same type as the parameter list).

Comment: I see what your saying, and that would work. But I don't want to risk the assignment on changing the method header. I think I want to do this by just modifying objectList. I tried doing this, and I've had a bit of a problem, I'm not home right now, I'll post my new code when I get back. I was just using a for loop and inserting the right entry into the left and vice versa then removing the excess terms. Does this sound like it will work?

Comment: If your function is two swap two cells of a list, your looking for a far two complicated solution. Use "set" instead of "add" and "remove".

Comment: Thats how I felt from the beginning, that what I was trying to do was too complex. Does set replace the index entirely?

Comment: Yes, [set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set(int,%20E)) replaces the item at the given index (and returns it).

Answer (score 0):

I first want to thank everyone who contributed to answering this question. I consulted with my teacher on office hours sometime last week. My teacher had me draw out a mental picture of what the problem was before writing the code, then a physical picture on paper and pencil of the process to be used. Finally after writing the code, here is the solution:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void swapCells
(ArrayList<E> objectList, int left, int right) {

    /*
     * Create a temporary generic object so that the left and
     * right objects can be swapped without losing any data.
     */
    E temp = objectList.get(left);

    // Place the right object into the left position
    objectList.set(left, objectList.get(right));

    /*
     * Place the temporary (left) object into the right
     * position.
     */
    objectList.set(right, temp);

} // End of swapCells
```

There was really no need to even create a second array list, when one can simply use a temporary object E.